# Exact match on all fields in index with filters

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm creating a search engine whereby the user can choose to search an exact term if they want to using quotations. For example, searching `"foo" bar` will do an exact match on `"foo"` throughout all fields.

I got this partially working with a `multi_match` but I could not specify to match the order of terms as well:

```
{
    "index": [],
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "multi_match": {
                            "query": "foo",
                            "operator": "and"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "should": [
                   ...
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is not desirable as I cannot specify to maintain the order of the terms. For example, I was trying to exact match `"foo bar"`, then that would return results which held `"bar foo"` in one of their fields.

Regarding the `should`, queries may or may not be here depending on what the user has searched but that is a standard Query String Query/match.

I am now looking to use `filter`s as it is what Elasticsearch [recommends](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html). My current query *(taken from the example)* is:

```
{
    "index": [],
    "body": {
        "query": {
            "constant_score": {
                "filter": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "_all": "foo"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "match_all": {}
        }
    }
}
```

`filter` is an array here as the user may specify to exact match on multiple different terms/phrases. For example, searching `"foo bar" hello "world"` would produce something like:

```
"filter": [
    {
        "term": {
            "_all": "foo bar"
        }
    },
    {
         "term": {
             "_all": "world"
         }
     }
 ]
```

The error I get is `[parsing_exception] unexpected token [START_ARRAY], with { line=1 & col=38 }`. The full stack trace is below:

[image]

I'm unsure whether the `match_all` is needed, I just threw that in there as I wasn't getting any output.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is `simple_query_string` and not multi_match. Another alternative is `match_phrase `, but with this you'll have to do the tokenizing yourself which is tedious. `simple_query_string` does that underneath, it parses your input and creates a bool query with match, match_phrase etc

Comment: Should I place my `simple_string_query` within a `must` or `should` within my `bool`?